# how to avoid that the scroll bar on the right overlaps with the top navbar (bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website with a navbar fixed to the top and a navbar on the left. When there is need for scrolling on the website, the scrollbar on the right overlaps with the top navbar. I would like the navbar to start below the top navbar.
I made a fiddle with an example of the problem

https://jsfiddle.net/jsmnsLm7/
(please make the window big, so that you can see all of the features of my navbar setup)

Here is the code which I also have in the fiddle (but stackoverlow forces me to put code in here as well... I think its much easier in the fiddle)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> 
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation" style="width: 180px; position: fixed;">
            <br><br><br>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">item0</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main" style="margin-left: 180px;">      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I saw that some discussed this problem before on stackoverflow, and they suggested to add position: fixed to the css of the container. However, when I do that, the left navbar gets fixed to the very left of the page. I want the left navbar to be flexible and synchronous with the top navbar (as shown in the fiddle example)
thanks for any help
best
carl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to tell the **body** not to use the scroll bars by setting `overflow:hidden;` .Then you need to move `.main` down a bit 50px as this is the headers height and tell it to scroll `overflow-y: scroll;` .However `.main` needs a height to be set and for that you need some Jquery code to calculate how much height is available on the window minus the 50px for the headers height.

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/ksroccd8/

**Css**

```
body {
overflow:hidden;
}
.main {
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Code**

```
//get window height minus 50 pixels for the headers height
var height = $(window).height() - 50;

$(".main").height(height);
```

When you resize the window you need to recalculate the height for `.main` and for that you will need window resize function to add

**Code**

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
var height = $(window).height() - 50;

$(".main").height(height);
};
```

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/a88n0aet/

Answer (score 7):

@Tasos' solution to hide body overflow is a good start, but using javascript to set the height doesn't work on browser resize events properly, at least on Chrome 59 (and document.height is [now deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/height)).

If you use `position:absolute`, `top` and `bottom` on `main`, you should be set: https://jsfiddle.net/vvsp60ya/

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</nav>
<main>
  <div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I recommend this answer for those using Angular2+

Comment: It is usually always better if it can be solved with CSS only and no additional scripts need to be run.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a slight modification in @Tasos' solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        resize();
    }); 
    function resize() {
        var myheight = $(window).outerHeight(true) - 50;
        $('.main').outerHeight(myheight);
    }
    resize();
});
```