# Vuetify navbar (v-app-bar) overlap scrollbar

Tags: css, vuetify.js

The same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497996/how-to-avoid-that-the-scroll-bar-on-the-right-overlaps-with-the-top-navbar-boot) except it is Vuetify.

Is there any solution that use provided API? CSS would be the last option I choose.

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/tan-n-nguyen/pen/LYjVwjV)

```html
<template>
  <v-app-bar app dark absolute class="navbar-bg" >
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="toggleSidebar" />

    <v-toolbar-title>Homepage</v-toolbar-title>

  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there's no a single prop in API.

But you may help yourself a lot with a built-in vuetify classes and directives.

First of all, you (sadly) need to write some CSS to manually disable initial page scrolling:

```
html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Then you need to add `<v-main>` component to your application with `scrollable pt-0 mt-16` classes and wrap all of your future app components into it. This classes will adjust the padding from the default `<v-app-bar>` and enable scrolling directly in `<v-main>`.

Finally, you should add `v-resize` directive to `<v-main>` to automatically recalculate your page size when user will resize a page:

```
<v-main class="scrollable pt-0 mt-16" v-resize="onResize">
    ...your application data...
</v-main>

...
methods: {
  onResize() {
    //64px is v-app-bar height in your case
    document.querySelector(".scrollable").style.height = (window.innerHeight - 64) + 'px';
  }
},
```

That's it. You may then create your custom component to wrap `<v-main>` and forget about such manipulations.

[Codepen link with an example](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/KKvdNqj)